# Issue with SaltStack

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, salt-stack

Recently I started taking an interest in Salt and begun doing a tutorial on it.I am currently working on a Mac and I having a hard time trying to start the vm[the minion] from my laptop[I am using Vagrant as an application to start the process]

The vagrant file for the vm contains these lines:

```
# salt-vagrant config
 config.vm.provision :salt do |salt|
 salt.run_highstate = true
 salt.minion_config = "/etc/salt/minion"
 salt.minion_key = "./minion1.pem"
 salt.minion_pub = "./minion1.pub"
end
```

even though I wrote this it gets stuck at:
`Calling state.highstate... (this may take a while)`

Any ideas why?

One more thing.I seem to need to modify the `top.sls` file at the next step which is located in `/srv/salt`.Unfortunately I can not find the `/srv` file anywhere,why is that?is there a way to tell the master that the top file is somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a `top.sls` created, then you won't be able to run a hightstate like you have configured with the `salt.run_highstate = true` line.

If you don't have a `/srv/salt/` directory created, then you can just create it yourself. Just make sure the user the salt-master is running as can read it.

The `/srv/salt/` directory is the default location of what is known as the `file_root`. You can modify its location in the master config file `/etc/salt/master` and modify the `file_roots` config option.